# how to store array of data without knowing the fields?

Tags: facebook, mongodb

I am currently developing a Facebook application that calls upon the API and retrieve the user's info and display them on the front end.

However, since there are so many fields in the data. Could i actually store them into an array without knowing the fields using MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

> Data in MongoDB has a flexible schema. Unlike SQL databases, where you
>   must determine and declare a table’s schema before inserting data,
>   MongoDB’s collections do not enforce document structure.

Read this articel: [Data Modeling Introduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)

Instead of inserting data to array you can insert it as a new key-value pair to document.